# Global Image Variables?

Tags: templating, assets, image, globals

I have setup a global set for images i use across the site. I have one for seo - where I have images for a twitter card and Facebook image in my seo settings. There is only one image for each field ( so hoping to avoid using the array syntax )

Two questions:

1. I am not sure how to access the images uploaded into this global variable. My global set has a handle "seo" and the image's handle is "twittercard". This isn't working :

   meta(name='twitter:image:', content='{{ image.getUrl('seo.twittercard') }}')
2. Is this the most efficient way to store images used globally across the site? ( via global image variables?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`seo.twittercard` is an [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel). To access the actual asset, you need to use `seo.twittercard.first` (or equivalently: `seo.twittercard.first()`).

However, you should always check that this exists before referencing it:

```
{% if seo.twittercard|length %}
  <meta(name='twitter:image:', content='{{ seo.twittercard.first.getUrl() }}')>
{% endif %}
```

And yes, this is a fine way to store images used globally across the site.

Comment: What is the benefit of doing the check ( if the image exists?). I am hoping to simplify the code by doing something like this ?    meta(name='twitter:image:src', content='{{ image.getUrl('seo.twittercard.first') }}')

Comment: The image might not exist. It might not have been initialized, or the asset might have been removed. And then your site will be mysteriously broken. I think it is always worth checking.

Comment: Thx. Will do then. However, I tried to see if i can simply output the url on the template ( before putting it in the wrapper to check if it exists ). this is not working:   {{ image.getUrl('seo.twittercard.first') }}')

Comment: oops! fixing my answer. You want `{{seo.twittercard.first.getUrl()}}`

Comment: boom! works nicely! Thx.

Answer (score 3):

This is a general structure to display global images in any template:

```
<img src="{{ globalHandle.globalAssetHandle.one().getUrl }}" alt="">
```

You have to set your global handle here:

[image]

And your global asset handle here:

[image]